# How do I add a device to Xcode devices?

Tags: xcode

I have an iPad and an iPhone.  My iPhone is listed under devices in Xcode, and I'm trying to add my iPad.

Q: How do I add a device in Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Xcode. Plug in the device. Follow the prompts.

Comment: Plug it in?!  I don't want to have to plug it in!  Just kidding.

Comment: My colleague tried this on a corporate account and had a certificate revoked from other people. Don't trust the robots to fix a complex issues, at least yet.

Answer (score 22):

Sometimes plugging in the device does not bring up the window.

In this case, from the Xcode menu, select Window and then Organizer.

Comment: Ok, it is not under Organizer any more with the new Xcode. It should be under Devices. Although I see no way to add the device to the Provisioning Profile here, and the auto fix does not work either. Is their a way to automatically have it added to the profile.

Comment: Down voted because this is no longer correct.  See MajorHavoc's comment above.

Answer (score 9):

Connect your device to your Mac with cable.

> 1. Open XCode
> 2. Window -> Devices & Simulators
> 3. Tap on your device
> 4. Tap to check on "Show as run destination"
> 5. Tap to check on "Connect via network"

Comment: after updating xcode there is no devices showing anymore. WTH

Comment: If one already has XCode open when the device is plugged-in, restart the program.  Then it will appear under devices & simulations

Answer (score 3):

Plug your device directly into your mac, don't go through a USB hub as in my case.  As soon as I went directly from iPhone to mac, it showed up.

Comment: If it doesn't appear when plugged into the USB, unplug the device, quit and restart Xcode, then plug in the device to the USB. This is what finally worked for me (Xcode 13.x)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Xcode
2. Window -> Devices & Simulators
3. On the bottom left of the Devices window is a "+" Sign, Click on it.
4. Choose a connected device from the list to setup
5. click "Next"
6. when complete Click "Done"
7. Disconnect and Reconnect the Device

Answer (score 1):

open xcode and in the above option => "Window" click and select " Devices and simulators ". In the opened window you can see bottom left side "+" button .
click and add your device

Comment: This information is covered in Geosaffer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added my iPhone,which had the same issue, by changing my deployment target to match the OS on my phone, selecting my phone in the simulation bar (by the play stop links) and clicking the fix issue link.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the device -> Open Xcode -> Click the top runner bar, select the connected device (you may need to scroll up). [image: Screenshot of top runner bar]

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you just to set the device to 'Developer Mode'...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).